# What is the difference between nesting module definitions and using :: in definition in ruby?

Tags: ruby, scope, constants

What are the differences between this:

```
module Outer
  module Inner
    class Foo
    end
  end
end
```

and this:

```
module Outer::Inner
  class Foo
  end
end
```

I know the latter example won't work if `Outer` was not defined earlier, but there are some other differences with constant scope and I could find their description on SO or in documentation (including Programming Ruby book)

Comment: I think "class A::B::MyClass" does work, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it works, but what is the difference between `class A::B::MyClass; end` and `module A; module B; class MyClass; end; end; end;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is at least one difference - constant lookup, check this code:

```
module A
  CONST = 1

  module B
    CONST = 2

    module C
      def self.const
        CONST
      end
    end
  end
end

module X
  module Y
    CONST = 2
  end
end

module X
  CONST = 1

  module Y::Z
    def self.const
      CONST
    end
  end
end

puts A::B::C.const # => 2, CONST value is resolved to A::B::CONST
puts X::Y::Z.const # => 1, CONST value is resolved to X::CONST
```

Comment: So, it uses lexical scope for constants and "jumps over" :: when walking module definitions up, correct?

Comment: i don't know details of their algorithm but it definitely looks like that. knowing that helps you to avoid debugging hell sometimes. i don't know of any other differences between 2 kinds of module/class definition.

Comment: Yes, this combined with Rails autoloading can lead to some hellish debugging :)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to keymone's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393398/169000) I formulated correct Google query and found this: [Module.nesting and constant name resolution in Ruby](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/constant-name-resolution-in-ruby/)

Using `::` changes constant scope resolution

```
module A
  module B
    module C1
      # This shows modules where ruby will look for constants, in this order
      Module.nesting # => [A::B::C1, A::B, A]
    end
  end
end

module A
  module B::C2
    # Skipping A::B because of ::
    Module.nesting # => [A::B::C2, A]
  end
end
```